# String pattern in Python

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

Im trying to check if a user's input is following the pattern integer/integer/integer(like month/day/year) but i dont know how to use exactly the match function to define that the pattern contains "number",then "/",again "number" and "/"...

Answer (score -2):

Check out https://regex101.com/ for a neat website to check your regex! This is implemented in python using the re library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

In your case, the pattern would be `[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4}`

Comment: This allows `00/00/2022`, or any number of other invalid dates. Also, simple questions such as this one have usually already been asked and answered on Stack Overflow. In such situations, the recommended action is to flag / vote to close this question as a duplicate, instead of adding an answer.

Comment: thank you ...that was exactly what i couldnt find